# Delphi: What to do when a form fails to free when logging out of an application

Tags: delphi, exception, forms, free, logout

I'm using Delphi (7-2010) and trying to figure out a good way to handle exceptions while freeing forms of an application.  The application has several forms that are owned by the Application object.  When the user logs out, I need to free all of the existing forms so no user state is maintained and then show the login dialog for the next user who logs in.

Occasionally, an exception happens while trying to free one of the forms.  That leaves the form in memory, but in an unknown/unusable state, so I can't re-use the form for the next user, and I also can't get rid of it from memory.  Because the forms are owned by the application, I can't directly create a new version of the form for the next user, since it would cause the "A component named MyForm already exists" error from the VCL, and I'm bit averse to having old form instances in memory anyway.

I'd like to see what others would do in this case.  Here are some ideas:

- Terminate the application when you get these exceptions, so you are sure to wipe the slate clean.  The user is logging out anyway, so they are likely done with the app.  Optionally restart the app if desired.
- Make the forms not owned by the Application, so you can create multiple instances of them, and make sure any non-freeable/broken forms are at least hidden.
- Dynamically generate the name of each form, or set it to blank, so there are never duplicate names, and no "already exists" errors from the VCL.
- Write an application so well that there are never exceptions when freeing objects (unrealistic - I need a contingency plan for unexpected errors).

---

**My Solution** was one of the original ideas above.  I added a try/except block around the loop that frees the forms, and if there is an exception, I show the error message to the user without raising it, and then call ExitProcess(0) to immediately kill the application.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's really no good way to handle exceptions raised from within a destructor.  And I wouldn't call it "unrealistic" to expect them never to be raised, since a destructor shouldn't do anything that can cause an exception.  If you're doing anything except freeing memory or other cleanup, (releasing handles, closing connections, etc.) you're almost certainly doing something wrong.

What's causing the exceptions, BTW?  Are you able to reproduce the error consistently?  Your best course of action is to just fix the errors.  There shouldn't be too many of them.

Comment: The errors represent any number of things.  Past examples were third party components that try to save their state and fail for whatever reason, exceptions disconnecting connections/datasets, AVs of an unknown cause, etc.  It isn't that these errors are numerous or common, but that I want to be proactive and make the application to act intelligently even in those rare cases where new/unexpected errors do show up.

Comment: @Anagoge: All right.  Well, if the user's logging out at the time anyway, I'd just terminate the app at that point, after dumping an exception log and sending it to you.  (If you don't have a way to do that, check out MadExcept or EurekaLog.  They're invaluable for tracking down bugs in deployed code, the next best thing to actually having a debugger connected to the user's app.)

Answer (score 5):

Most of the time, errors happen when destroying forms because there is still some event handler executing and referring to an already destroyed object.
That's why **`TForm.Release`** has been created to be used in place of **`TForm.Free`** in such cases.

From the help:
*Use Release to destroy the form and free its associated memory. 
Release does not destroy the form until all event handlers of the form and event handlers of components on the form have finished executing. Release also guarantees that all messages in the form's event queue are processed before the form is released. Any event handlers for the form or its children should use Release instead of Free (Delphi) or delete (C++). Failing to do so can cause a memory access error.*